# How to use custom y-axis values in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a lineplot of values for different cars, and want to replace the y-axis values (1,2,3..) with the corresponding carnames. My goal is to show which cars ranked where for year1 (on the left) and year4 (on the right).

Here is data:

```
df=  mtcars %>%
    select(mpg,disp,wt,qsec) %>%
    rownames_to_column("car") %>%
    slice_head(n = 10) %>% 
    remove_rownames() %>% rename(car=1, 'year1'=2, 'year2'=3, 'year3'=4, 'year4'=5) %>% 
    COINr::rank_df() %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -car, names_to = "year", values_to = "rank") %>% arrange(car, year)
```

And here is current plot:
[image]

```
my_colors <- c("#1b9e77", "#d95f02", "#7570b3", "#e7298a", "#66a61e",
               "#e6ab02", "#a6761d", "#666666", "#e78ac3", "#984ea3")

 ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = rank, group = car, color = car)) +
    geom_line(size = 2) +
    geom_point(size = 6) +
    geom_text(aes(label = rank), vjust = 0.6, size = 3.5, color = 'white') + labs(x='', y='')+
    scale_color_manual(values = my_colors) +
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = 1:nrow(df)) +  
     theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = 'bottom')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer @Axeman's approach, but you might also consider adding annotation layers like so:

```
...
geom_text(aes(label = car, hjust = 1),
          position = position_nudge(x = -0.1),
          data = . %>% filter(year == min(year))) +
geom_text(aes(label = car, hjust = 0),
          position = position_nudge(x = 0.1),
          data = . %>% filter(year == max(year))) +
coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
```

(note: My ranking is all off b/c I used `arrange(year, value, car) %>% mutate(rank = row_number(), .by = year)` instead of  `COINr::rank_df()`. But you get the idea...)

[image]

Or with less theming:

```
  geom_text(aes(label = car, hjust = 1),
            position = position_nudge(x = -0.1),
            data = . %>% filter(year == min(year))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = car, hjust = 0),
            position = position_nudge(x = 0.1),
            data = . %>% filter(year == max(year))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = c(0.5, 4.5)) +
  theme_void() +
  guides(color = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We just need to correctly match the `breaks` and `labels`, and use the identity transformation (`I`). Here is one way of doing it:

```
+ scale_y_reverse(
    breaks = 1:n_distinct(df$car),
    labels = df %>% filter(year == 'year1') %>% arrange(rank) %>% pull(car),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      trans = I,
      breaks = 1:n_distinct(df$car),
      labels = df %>% filter(year == 'year4') %>% arrange(rank) %>% pull(car)
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another nice option here is `ggbump`, which often shows the transitions more clearly, with a nice aesthetic. The [readme](https://github.com/davidsjoberg/ggbump?tab=readme-ov-file#pimp-the-bump-chart) even shows how to produce the labels in the format you are looking for.

In your case, a full reprex would look like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbump)

my_colors <- c("#1b9e77", "#d95f02", "#7570b3", "#e7298a", "#66a61e",
               "#e6ab02", "#a6761d", "#666666", "#e78ac3", "#984ea3")

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg,disp,wt,qsec) %>%
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  slice_head(n = 10) %>% 
  remove_rownames() %>% 
  rename(car=1, 'year1'=2, 'year2'=3, 'year3'=4, 'year4'=5) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('year'), ~rank(-.x, ties = 'first'))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-car, names_to = 'year', values_to = 'rank') %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(sub('year', '', year))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, rank, color = car, group = car)) +
  geom_bump(linewidth = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = rank), color = 'white', fontface = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = car, x = 0.5), color = 'black', hjust = 1,
            data = . %>% filter(year == 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = car, x = 4.5), color = 'black', hjust = 0,
            data = . %>% filter(year == 4)) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  xlim(c(-1, 6)) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_colors, guide = 'none')
```

[image]